# Getting different ids from console vs. command line - recommended Identity Management in Google Compute (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'm getting confusing results when using GCP from the command line vs. the GCP console. It causes multiple users to be set up, and I also suspect it is causing SSH issues.

Let's say my google email is joe@gmail.com, but that my local username is joseph.

Logging into the GCP VM can give me three different identities:

**Using the console**: joe@VMNAME

**Using the command line** gcloud compute ssh: joseph@VMNAME

**Using OS login from command line**: joe_gmail_com@VMNAME

Which identity is best to use? And how do I set things up so I only use one?

Comment: What does `gcloud auth list` show for the active account? Does it match the Console login? My guess is that you have several identities that you have logged in as in the past. I do not know of a way to change the OS Login method.

Comment: Look at the keys in `~/.ssh`. What user name is near the bottom of the public key file?

Comment: Thanks John!

gcloud auth list produces

 Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       joseph@gmail.com

The public ssh file ends with my local user id joe@ubu-dt

Which one of these do you suggest I try to change?

Comment: Change the public key username `joe` to match your Google Account `joseph`.